# Boolean in ANTLR4?

Tags: boolean, antlr4

This is my code :

```
grammar test;
assignStatement : ID '=' BOOL ';' ;
ID : ID_LETTER (ID_LETTER | DIGIT)* ;  
fragment ID_LETTER : [a-z] | [A-Z] | '_' ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;
BOOL : 'true' | 'false' ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

But when i test it with the sentence :

```
x = true ;
```

It has an error :

```
mismatched input 'true' expecting BOOL
```

Why did i have this error ? How to fix it ? Your help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lexer will match the ID rule first because order matters. Therefore, move your BOOL rule above it to fix this:

```
assignStatement : ID '=' BOOL ';' ;

fragment ID_LETTER : [a-z] | [A-Z] | '_' ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;

BOOL : 'true' | 'false' ;
ID : ID_LETTER (ID_LETTER | DIGIT)* ;

WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```